# DRYing MVC helper options

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dry

Imagine A MVC view that contains a grid:

```
@{
    Html.Grid(
        autoGenerateColumn: false,
        Url : "/Grid/GetData",
        columnBuilderAction: p =>
        {
            p.Add(c => c.Name, "100");
            p.Add(c => c.Code, "100").AlignCenter();
        }    
   );
}
```

The URL specify the action that returns a json array contains data for filling the grid.
Obviously "/Grid/GetData" should returns only Name and Code property of person, but person have more properties.

It is violation of DRY if we specified this properties in GetData action

It will take more traffic if we pass this properties from client (with Ajax request of grid) to action

It is not beautiful (in my opinion!) if this properties define in controller, pass with ViewData to grid and shared with GetData action

Is ther any best practices or suitable practices!

Comment: For similar issues, we usually end up with a custom layer between the db and MVC that allows for the retrieval of custom lists (i.e. lists where you only want a given set of properties. `SelectList` is often the first to be implemented). The entire layer consists of static functions that run custom LINQ `Select(lambda)` statements. Not sure if other people would agree with this :)

Comment: @Flater: static functions sound like something that could be refactored into proper services with instance methods and injectable dependencies.

Comment: @WiktorZychla: My projects never reach a size or scope where such an implementation is relevant.

Answer (score 0):

In the controller is where you define what view to show (or in your case the information to be passed to the view).

In this case... you have a controller `Persons`, and a Index action. In the Index view... you setup your grid.

So... for me is perfectly fine to provide a sub set of Person properties, just for the view. Remember that you are supposed to send VIEWMODELS to views, not domain models. So, in this case... if you just need Name and Code... you can create a `QuickPerson` class with those properties... and in you database query do:

```
  .Select(x => new QuickPerson(){ Code = x.Code, Name = x.Name})
```

Not sure if the `columnBuilderAction` can detect the properies automatically to avoid this.

What happend if you don't set the columnBuilder? If it uses all the public properties of the model... then you just solved the issue, since your new `QuickPerson` model has just the needed ones.

Comment: The problem with QuickPerson is in filtering and sorting, columnBuilder build grid columns and filter box then our query engine automatically add required filtering and sorting to query. but the query engine does no know anythings about QuickPerson, it works only with entities.